# Using double quotes with MATCHES in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to filter my input in pig based on a string pattern which has double quotes in it.

For example, say the input.txt has

```
field1="value1" field2="value2"
field1="value1" field2="val2"
```

I want to filter out lines which has field2="value2". So, I run the following script

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line:chararray;
B = FILTER A BY line MATCHES '.*field2="value2".*';
DUMP B;
```

The above code snippet throws up 0 records. If I don't give the ending double quote, it works

```
B = FILTER A BY line MATCHES '.*field2="value2.*';
```

I'd love to know why the former doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the escape chacacter for quotes:

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line:chararray;
B = FILTER A BY line MATCHES '.*field2=\\"value2\\".*';
DUMP B;
```

Comment: Thanks for you time. I tried that before I posted this question. It didn't work. That's because it's actually escaping the backslash and not the double quote. 

PS: I am sorry for the late response. (I thought I posted my response earlier but I clearly I didn't.)